# Unix command to insert a comment on the top of all files in a directory

Tags: linux, file, shell, unix, find

I want to add a comment to all files in a directory in Unix. Please suggest a solution if there is any combination of commands I can use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `find` and `sed`:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sed -i '1i #comment' {} \;
```

This will add the line `#comment` to the top of all the files in the current directory

Comment: Or replace the `\;` with `+` to process several files in a single invocation of `sed`.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this using a simple `shell` concatenation :

```
for i in *; do
    { echo '# this is a comment'; cat "$i"; } > /tmp/_$$file &&
    mv /tmp/_$$file "$i"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

For the fun, try doing this using [ed](/questions/tagged/ed) :

```
echo $'1i\n# comment\n.\nw\nq' | ed -s file.txt
```

*Here-doc* version :

```
ed -s file.txt <<EOF
1i
# comment
.
w
q
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a comment to all files with an extension (e.g. ".rb"):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.rb" -exec sed -i '1i #comment' {} \;
```

And recursive:

```
find . -type f -name "*.rb" -exec sed -i '1i #comment' {} \;
```